# Huawei Developer Console : How to transfer an app from one developer accout to another？

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

we are trying to transfer one of the projects from one account to the other in https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/console

But since the package name and everything is already exist in the system, It is not allowing the create the same project again.

Is there any way to transfer my application to the different account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can transfer your application to the different account. Here is an official guide about how to transfer your application : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/50112